# Where is the Israeli Niggun sung after a Mazel Tov from?

Tags: minhag, music

In Israel it is customary to sing a wordless niggun after a mazel tov is read out in shul. (The only rendition I could find is [here](https://youtu.be/fr_nMPspWuE?t=808), excuse the cats). Where is this niggun from? Who wrote it?

Comment: I know it as a Gerrer Niggun.

Comment: @פריזהב Right you are -- just found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ernnuEpDim0.

Answer (score 2):

@פרי זהב answered this -- it's a Gerrer niggun, as sung here by Yitzchak Meir: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ernnuEpDim0

Comment: YOU MIGHT WARN US BEFORE WE CLICK ON THE LINK THAT IT'S NOT A CAPELLA!!! It's the Three Weeks remember?

Comment: @ezra **You** just warned us :-)